# How to store response token & logout using that token from react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on an app to log in using api and log out by using the retrieved token.

This is my App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import AppNavigator from './src/navigations/Navigator';
    import * as Font from 'expo-font';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    state= {
    isReady : false
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
    Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
    Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
   ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
    }

   render() {
   return (
   <AppNavigator />
   );
   }
   }
```

This is my navigator.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
    import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
    import Login from '../screens/Login';
    import QrScan from '../screens/qrscan';

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login:{
    screen:Login,
    navigationOptions : {
    headerShown:false
    }
    },
    QrScan:{
    screen:QrScan,
    navigationOptions : {
      headerTitle:''
    }
    }
    },

    );
    export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

This is login screen login.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Button,Text,View,Image,TextInput,SafeAreaView,ImageBackground,Alert} from 'react-native';

    export default class Login extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

    UserName: '',
    UserPassword: ''

    }

    }

    UserLoginFunction = () =>{

    const { UserName }  = this.state ;
    const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;
    
    
    fetch('https://api.idepoz.com/ncl/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    
        username: UserName,
    
        password: UserPassword
    
    })
    
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            //console.log(responseJson);
            
            if(responseJson)
            {
                
            this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'QrScan'});
    
            }
            else{
    
                Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }
    
            }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            });

            }

            render(){
            const {navigate} = this.props.navigation
            return(
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1,
            }}>
            <ImageBackground
                style={{ flex: 1,width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                //We are using online image to set background
                source={require('../images/rsz_care.jpg')}   
                 
            >    
      
        
            <View style={{
                flexDirection:"row",
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems:"center",
                marginHorizontal:55,
                borderWidth:2,
                marginTop:100,
                paddingHorizontal:10,
                borderColor:"#00716F",
                borderRadius:23,
                paddingVertical:2
            }}>
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Enter Username"
                    style={{paddingHorizontal:10}}
                    onChangeText={UserName => this.setState({UserName})}
                />

                </View>
                <View style={{
                flexDirection:"row",
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems:"center",
                marginHorizontal:55,
                borderWidth:2,
                marginTop:15,
                paddingHorizontal:10,
                borderColor:"#00716F",
                borderRadius:23,
                paddingVertical:2
                }}>
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                    style={{paddingHorizontal:10}}
                    onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}
                />
                </View>

                <View style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems:"center",
                marginTop:15
                }}>
                <Button title="Forward" onPress={this.UserLoginFunction} color= "#00716F"/>
                
                </View>
                </ImageBackground>
        
                </SafeAreaView>
                )
                }
                }
```

Th following page is loaded when successfully log in qrscan.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Container, Header, Title, Drawer, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Text } from 'native-base';
    import { Alert } from 'react-native';
    import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import SideBar from './components/SideBar';

    export default class QrScan extends React.Component{
    closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close();
    }
    openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open();
    }
    render()
    {
    return(
        <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}/>}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}>
                            <MaterialIcons name="list" size={40} color="#FFFFFF" />
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title></Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Ionicons  name="search" size={40} color="#FFFFFF" onPress={() => Alert.alert('Search Button pressed')} />
                    </Button>   
                    </Right>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <Text>
                        
                    </Text>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        </Drawer>
    );
    }
    }
```

The following is the sidebar i am using for drawer

```
     import React from 'react';
     import { Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
     import { Drawer,Container, Content, Header, Right, Button } from 'native-base';
     import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 


     export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
     render() {
     return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
            <Right>
                <Button transparent>
                    <FontAwesome  name="close" size={24} color="#FFFFFF" onPress={() => this.props.closeDrawer()} />
                </Button>   
            </Right>
            </Header>
            <Content>
                <Button transparent onPress={}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>Log Out</Text>       
            </Button> 
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
    }
    }
```

I can log in using the api. I am retrieving token, i have console logged it. But i can't store the token and i am trying to logout from the sidebar using that token. Can anyone help?

Comment: Give `AsyncStorage` a look for a device storage solution on react-native

Comment: I am new to react native. I have come up with something like this,           
                                          
         storeToken(responseJson){
        AsyncStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, responseJson, (err)=> {
            if(err){
       
            throw err;
            } else{
            this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'QrScan'}); 
            }
        }).catch((err)=> {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
        });
    };                                                                                            but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global state to store the user information and access it anywhere on the screen.

Global State management:

- React Redux
- Context API

check out the docs for more information:

https://www.toptal.com/react/react-context-api

https://react-redux.js.org/